# Trouble Parsing XML in Python with xml.doc.minidom

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I am trying to get the lot size of a house from Zillow's API, but I am not printing out the correct result.

My goal is to print out the value in the XML field of "lotSizeSqFt".  Whenever I print, all I get is empty square brackets.  Anybody know what's going on?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urllib, urllib2
import csv

from xml.dom import minidom
import xml.dom.minidom

#makes an api call for a given address
def makeCall(address, cityStateZip):
    url = "http://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetDeepSearchResults.htm?zws-id=X1-ZWz1bah9j0jpqj_493z4&address=" + address + "&citystatezip=" + cityStateZip

    #parse the XML document
    xml = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    xmldoc = minidom.parse(xml)

    return xmldoc



def getData(address, cityStateZip):

    #returns parsed XML doc
    xmldoc = makeCall(address, cityStateZip)

    #get necesary data
    lotsize =  xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("lotSizeSqFt")

    return lotsize


address = "10608 Floral Park Lane"
cityStateZip = "North Potomac, MD 20878"

print getData(address, cityStateZip)
```

Comment: First of all, when i tried to access this url, I received this error: "Error: this account has reached is maximum number of calls for today". Better to try tomorrow.

Comment: I get the same thing. The good news is, it looks like your code is working (there really are no lotSizeSqFt elements)! For future reference, the `[]` is pythons way of showing an empty list - e.g. "no results".